# How the Thread will get terminate successfully in Spring Async function and how to call same function recursively in multi threaded method in java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I am calling `@Async` function from my controller and looks like the thread is not getting terminated after completing the `makeCallWithRestTemplate` method from `HttpServiceClient` class.

- **Question 1-** How do I make sure that the thread will get closed after performing its task?
- I have two types of task - independent task and dependent task.
  Now my requirement is I will get list of tasks as a input and I would need to execute all independent task first, then execute dependent task based on some condition like below
- **Question 2-** once all the independent task will get executed wait here, Now my question is how to wait here ?
- **Question 3-** once wait complete again call restTemplate.exchange method with dependent task, how can i make it recursive, will my hashmap would be threadsafe in recursive?
- **Question 4-** In `makeCallWithRestTemplate` method , I am using hashmap which is further getting pass to extracted private method, now my next question is, is hashmap safe here in multithreaded environment, because for me it is a local variable which would be different for different Thread? or do i need to use ConcurrentHashmap here? How to test it?

Request structure

```
[ 
    { independent task 1
    },
    { dependent task 1,
        "dependency": { // dependency is that, execute task 1 first 
                        and then based on its result code execute dependent task 1
            "===": [
            "$[0].response.http_body.action.result_code",
            "SUCCESS"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc")
public class ActionController {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServiceClient client;
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> performMultipleActions(@RequestBody List<List<ABC>> abc) {
            return client.callExternalService(abc);
    }
}

@Component
public class HttpServiceClient {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate; 
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Map<Integer, ResponseEntity<JsonNode>>> makeCallWithRestTemplate(
            List<ABC> requests) throws IOException { 
        int index = -1;
        Map map = new hashmap();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
        index++;
        Abc abc = iterator.next();
        if (dependency == null) {
           extracted(mapOfResult, index, action);
        }else{
        //create a map of with index as a key and object as a value
        map.put(index, request); 
        }
        // **Question 3-** once all the independent task will get executed wait here, Now my question is how to wait here ? 
        //**Question 4-** once wait complete again call restTemplate.exchange method with dependent task, how can i make it recursive, will my hashmap would be threadsafe in recursive?
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(exchange);
    }
}
private void extracted(Map<Integer, ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> mapOfResult, int index, ActionRequest action)
            throws JsonProcessingException, JsonMappingException {
 ResponseEntity<JsonNode> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(urlObj,
                            HttpMethod.resolve(action.getMethod()), entity, JsonNode.class); 
    mapOfResult.put(index, exchange);
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't, the framework handles that, 2. use a completable future and join them. Overall looks like you are building something too complex and too flexible to work with.

Comment: @Deinum Thanks for quick response, is there any way i can resolve question 3 which would work in N numbers of independent and dependent task?